# Añadir subdominio al usar beginForm Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Buenas.

Estoy realizando un aplicación en ASP.NET MVC y al publicarlo no me funciona correctamente porque las rutas no son correctas.

Digamos que está publicado en

> https://test.depruebas.es/jgs/p12/Chat

La primera pantalla de login que es la que inicia el proyecto la muestra bien, pero cuando le doy al botón del BeginForm del formulario, me deberia enviar al controller Home y el action Index

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

Al pulsar el botón me establece esta ruta:

> test.depruebas.es/Chat/Home/Index

pero en realidad deberia de poner

> test.depruebas.es/jgs/p12/Chat/Home/Index

En el archivo Startup tengo definida esta ruta

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Login}/{id?}");         
        });
```

Y aqui los controller. El de Login es el primero que se inicia y saca el formulario, y al pulsar el boton de login te deberia lleva al Index, pero se forma mal la ruta como puse anteriormente.

```
public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

 public IActionResult Index([FromForm] DataChat model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(model.name != null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Login");             
            }

        }
        return View("Login");
    }
```

Comment: ¿Hay que configurar el Startup?

Comment: Pareciera más un problema de como tienes la acción de tu botón que de la forma como tal. Será que nos pudieras compartir tu código completo de la vista?